# What causes Voltage fluctuation in Panel

Tags: electrical-panel

I have a double pole 20 amp breaker in my main panel (no sub panels). and measuring the voltage it jumps between 118 and 121 on one side and 117 and 121 on the other. 
I thought it should be at 120V. why is it fluctuating so? Is this ok?

Comment: WOW you have GREAT voltage stability!!! I have seen residential mains from 108v through 126v or so in a 3 hour power survey. This is really good! I can drop my voltage on my house main by 2× this if I turn on a 30hp irrigation pump.

Comment: OP the important thing is that L1-N roughly equals L2-N.  Having a problem with L1 and L2 is merely annoying, having a problem with N is dangerous.   @EdBeal dude, a 30hp irrigation pump is like 93 amps.  That's not even legal to put on most residential service around here.

Comment: Actually it has a separate service from the same transformer that feeds my barn and the starter is 125 amp, its great to have water rights. All I have to do is pay for the power and move the water lines to keep my fields green. But when I kick it on it will draw down the voltage 12-15v.

Comment: yikes. well ok then. I don't run anything like that though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fluctuating within spec, because your household (and neighborhood) electric system is real, not "ideal."

The "240V" feed to my building varies between 238 and 242 on a regular basis - this depends on what other loads the system is servicing and the resistance of real wires with resistance. Actually, it's pretty impressive that the variation is that **small**, when you consider the distances involved and the number of separate, uncoordinated loads the power company has to supply, as they turn on, or off, at random.

Within your house, you may see variation on the two (115-125V) legs due to more loads on one leg than the other (unbalanced) - but the overall voltage into the building also varies slightly.

Comment: I'd upvote your answer as well, but I'm not allowed :(

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A key clarification is: you are measuring your voltage *with what*?  Typical low-end multimeters have *specified* AC voltage errors on the order of 2-3%.  I.e., the ranges you measured are consistent with true voltage being exactly 120VAC (RMS), and *could* just reflect the device's sampling error.

Answer (score 0):

I would wish these voltages all day long.   If that's the worst you ever see, your power is very good.  Consider yourself lucky to have good stable power like that.

Comment: well, as opposed to my neighbors, I am connected directly to the transformer. That could be the difference?